# std::pair assigning first and second to semantically named variables

Tags: c++, reference, std-pair

There is a very popular question about "std::pair vs struct with two fields". But I have a question about reassigning `first` and `second` values to semantically named variables. In regular scenario we have something like this:

```
const std::pair<const int, const int> result = processSomething();
std::cout << result.second << " of " << result.first << std::endl;
```

But what if we assign them to reference variables first:

```
const std::pair<const int, const int> result = processSomething();
const int &numTotal = result.first;
const int &numSuccessful = result.second;

std::cout << numSuccessful << " of " << numTotal << std::endl;
```

This freeing us from writing comments about semantics of `first` and `second`. What disadvantages of this way? Do compilers will reserve stack for `numTotal` and `numSuccessful`? Will perfomance drop if this pattern used in main loop of application?

### Fixes

Changed from regular variables to reference variables (thank you for comments)

Comment: Have you considered using references?

Comment: You can use references: `const int &numTotal = pair.first;`.

Comment: For clearer and more streamlined code, consider C++11's [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) (which assigns directly to named variables using a pair of references), which should even be faster *in cases where it matters* (not `int`s of course). Unfortunately the language doesn't yet allow tied construction (meaning you have to first define the variables before using the `tie`-trick).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't see any serious disadvantages, variables with meaningful names can help make the code much clearer.  A decent optimizing compiler should be able to remove any overhead from the extra references in simple cases such as your example, but maybe not for more complex cases where the types are not identical (e.g. they have different const-qualification or require conversions).

There is another option that might be clearer in some cases: Instead of initializing a `pair` with the result, you could create the variables you want, then create a `pair` of references to those variables, and assign to them via the references:

```
int numTotal;
int NumSuccessful;
std::pair<int&, int&> result(numTotal, numSuccessful);
result = processSomething();
```

Or the same thing, without a named variable for the pair of references:

```
int numTotal;
int NumSuccessful;
std::pair<int&, int&>(numTotal, numSuccessful) = processSomething();
```

or in C++11 you can use the standard `tie` function:

```
int numTotal;
int NumSuccessful;
std::tie(numTotal, numSuccessful) = processSomething();
```

A more unusual solution involves no temporary objects and allows you to make the variables `const`, by using a local type with meaningful member names:

```
struct Num {
  Num(std::pair<const int, const int> p) : total(p.first), successful(p.second) { }
  int total;
  int sucessful;
};
const Num num = processSomething();
std::cout << num.successful << '/' << num.total << '\n';
```

Comment: Note that `std::tie` does not produce a pair, but a tuple of references. The difference can be rather important.

Comment: @Xarn, yes, that's the point. You can assign a `pair<const int, const int>` to a `tuple<int&, int&>`, so it does what's needed.

Comment: I understand the OP question as, is the extra variable (aliases) really exist or are elided by optimizer.

Comment: The second piece of code is good, but still from compiler point of view he calling constructor inside `processSomething()` and then calling copy constructor outside, so I think `struct` still better approach for C++98 :(